# Getting NaN error

Tags: javascript, jquery, nan

I am using jQuery `.data` to store the number of clicks on an element. I can add to the value fine, but subtracting gives a NaN error. The value only increases. How can I fix this?

HTML:

```
<div data-click="0">Click here</div>
```

JS:

```
$("div").on("click", function(){
    console.log('Current: '+$(this).data('click'))
    $(this).data('click',$(this).data('click')+1);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(this).data('click',$(this).data('click')-1);
        console.log('After: '+$(this).data('click'))
    },1000);        
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bhmC9/

Comment: `NaN` is not an error, and you could at least tell us the line you are getting that on.

Comment: I figured out what he was talking about pretty easily...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When inside the `setTimeout` callback, `this` does not have the value you expect it to. Preserve it this way:

```
var that = this;
setTimeout(function(){
    $(that).data('click',$(that).data('click')-1);
    console.log('After: '+$(that).data('click'))
},1000);
```

In fact, `$(this)` appears so many times in that snippet that caching it sounds like a good idea. In addition, it also eliminates the need for watching out what `this` is:

```
var $this = $(this);
console.log('Current: '+$this.data('click'))
$this.data('click',$this.data('click')+1);
setTimeout(function(){
    $this.data('click',$this.data('click')-1);
    console.log('After: '+$this.data('click'))
},1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also set the scope of `this` within the function like so (by calling `bind`):

```
$("div").on("click", function(){
    console.log('Current: '+$(this).data('click'))
    $(this).data('click',$(this).data('click')+1);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(this).data('click',$(this).data('click')-1);
        console.log('After: '+$(this).data('click'))
    }.bind(this),1000);        
});
```